# Android NDK: How to get a Context from inside NDK code

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-activity

Writing a C++ shared library to be called by code written by others. I need to make Java library calls that require a Context, and the question is how to get one, starting from scratch.

I don't know much about my caller's environment, but it probably isn't on the UI thread and in any case I can't require the caller to pass in an Activity or an Application.

I do have access to the OnLoad() so I have a JavaVM and from that I can get a JNIEnv and a working class loader. Somewhere out there is an ApplicationContext, but is there a way to find it?

There is this code, but this is not the answer.
[android Flurry integration with NDK app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586821/android-flurry-integration-with-ndk-app)

There are also answers based on ActivityManager, but big warnings saying don't do that.

Suggestions?

Comment: There are situations where a process can have multiple contexts (e.g. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation.html).  How hard is the requirement that the app can't pass a Context into your library?

Comment: I assume every Activity has its own Context and that of the Application, so 2 would appear to be a minimum. Would there be more?
I simply don't own or control the calling code. The caller may not even know a Context; the caller could be another SO just like mine.