# JNIEnv FindClass can't find my package class

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, jnienv

I build Android NDK application in Android Studio. I've subclassed `NativeActivity` to add some Java code into my app. And I can't get this activity class with `JNIEnv::FindClass` on the C++ side. I know that:

1. I can call FindClass in Java thread only (I do so)
2. I should use full `/`-separated path to my class (`/com/my_package/MyActivity`)
3. The class should be public (not sure if it really should, but it is public, just in case)

Also, `FindClass` for "built-in" classes, like `android/net/Uri`, `android/content/Intent`, etc works fine. I can call Java methods from C++ - all that works fine. However `FindClass` for my own class doesn't work.

Googling for the similar errors didn't match my case. At least nothing helped from what I found. I work in Windows 7 (not sure if it matters).

Comment: I hope you mean `com/my_package/MyActivity` without the leading slash. Anyway, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14586821/android-flurry-integration-with-ndk-app

Comment: Yea, sorry, just a typo. No leading slashes in my code. Thank you for the link, looks promising. I'll try it tomorrow and get back here with results.

Comment: Hey Michael. Thank you very much, that's exactly my case, the problem is solved! A pity that I can't mark a comment as a solution to the question!